# How to install this update in windows 10: DST changes in Windows for Chile

Tags: windows-10, update, windows-update, automatic-updates

According to this page: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4486459/dst-changes-in-windows-for-chile, for Windows 10, all updates, including this one, are installed automatically, however, it did not occured in my case.

I have a Windows 10 miniPC with patches up-to-date, however, that patch is not installed because DST change is not applied (I cannot see the correct DST changes).

Is there a way to install that patch manually in Windows 10, or if it is actually applied, why doesn't it work? I have set regional settings to Chile localization.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

My Windows 10 version is 1803.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's updated on my Windows 10 computer, and was introduced in the February cumulative update.  The article you referenced states the registry key name is Chile Standard Time, but I don't have that on my system.  Compare these to your system:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\Pacific SA Standard Time]
"Display"="(UTC-04:00) Santiago"
"Dlt"="Pacific SA Daylight Time"
"MUI_Display"="@tzres.dll,-90"
"MUI_Dlt"="@tzres.dll,-91"
"MUI_Std"="@tzres.dll,-92"
"Std"="Pacific SA Standard Time"
"TZI"=hex:f0,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,04,00,06,00,01,00,17,00,3b,\
  00,3b,00,e7,03,00,00,09,00,06,00,01,00,17,00,3b,00,3b,00,e7,03

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\Pacific SA Standard Time\Dynamic DST]
"2007"=hex:f0,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,03,00,06,00,02,00,17,00,\
  3b,00,3b,00,e7,03,00,00,0a,00,06,00,02,00,17,00,3b,00,3b,00,e7,03
"2008"=hex:f0,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,03,00,06,00,05,00,17,00,\
  3b,00,3b,00,e7,03,00,00,0a,00,06,00,02,00,17,00,3b,00,3b,00,e7,03
"2009"=hex:f0,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,03,00,06,00,02,00,17,00,\
  3b,00,3b,00,e7,03,00,00,0a,00,06,00,02,00,17,00,3b,00,3b,00,e7,03
"2010"=hex:f0,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,04,00,06,00,01,00,17,00,\
  3b,00,3b,00,e7,03,00,00,0a,00,06,00,02,00,17,00,3b,00,3b,00,e7,03
"2011"=hex:f0,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,05,00,06,00,01,00,17,00,\
  3b,00,3b,00,e7,03,00,00,08,00,06,00,03,00,17,00,3b,00,3b,00,e7,03
"2012"=hex:f0,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,04,00,06,00,05,00,17,00,\
  3b,00,3b,00,e7,03,00,00,09,00,06,00,01,00,17,00,3b,00,3b,00,e7,03
"2013"=hex:f0,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,04,00,06,00,05,00,17,00,\
  3b,00,3b,00,e7,03,00,00,09,00,06,00,01,00,17,00,3b,00,3b,00,e7,03
"2014"=hex:f0,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,04,00,06,00,05,00,17,00,\
  3b,00,3b,00,e7,03,00,00,09,00,06,00,01,00,17,00,3b,00,3b,00,e7,03
"2015"=hex:b4,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"2016"=hex:f0,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,05,00,06,00,02,00,17,00,\
  3b,00,3b,00,e7,03,00,00,08,00,06,00,02,00,17,00,3b,00,3b,00,e7,03
"FirstEntry"=dword:000007d7
"LastEntry"=dword:000007e3
"2017"=hex:f0,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,05,00,06,00,02,00,17,00,\
  3b,00,3b,00,e7,03,00,00,08,00,06,00,02,00,17,00,3b,00,3b,00,e7,03
"2018"=hex:f0,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,05,00,06,00,02,00,17,00,\
  3b,00,3b,00,e7,03,00,00,08,00,06,00,02,00,17,00,3b,00,3b,00,e7,03
"2019"=hex:f0,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,04,00,06,00,01,00,17,00,\
  3b,00,3b,00,e7,03,00,00,09,00,06,00,01,00,17,00,3b,00,3b,00,e7,03
```

This is how it appears in TZEdit:

[image: Santiago Time Zone]

If these values don't match your systems, you can import the registry values and restart the system(s).

Comment: Thanks.... when seeing Dynamic DST settings, list appeared until year 2016. How may this happen? "Pacific SA Standard Time" appeared incorrect too... I updated the registry and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

> This update applies to the following operating systems:
>
> Windows Server 2012 R2 Windows 8.1 Windows RT 8.1 Windows Server 2008
>   R2 Service Pack 1 (SP1) Windows 7 SP1 Windows Server 2008 Service Pack
>   2 (SP2)
>
> Note To get the update for Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016, install
>   the latest cumulative updates that are listed in the Windows 10 and
>   Windows Server 2016 update history Knowledge Base article.

Comment: ?? Did you read the question carefully? I told that even the system is up-to-date, time zone is not updated (when you click the link shown in the page I referenced, and you have copied and pasted, it is suggested that Windows 10 should update it automatically, but even when system is up-to-date, the DST does not work)